# Cannot align divs

Tags: html

I cannot align my inline-block div (which contains multiple equal divs in it) to the center, it positions itself to the bottom

Float, vertical allgnment

```css
.oneline {
  width: 220px;
  height: 144px;
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: px;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: right; margin-right:140px;">
  <div class="oneline">
    <img src="gold.png" align="left">
    <pre>IV-III 12€
    III-II 12€
    II-I 12€
    I-SERIES 15€
    PLAT SERIES 9€
    PL WIN 5€
    </pre>
  </div>
  <p>2 MORE SAME DIVS</p>
  <hr>
  <p>3 MORE SAME DIVS</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-bottom: px;` ?

Comment: The opening divs don't match the closing divs. Indenting your code goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I added a class `.wrapper` to the outer-most div and moved your inline styles over to CSS. Added a red border so you could see better...

Flexbox layout makes centering a row or column of content very easy. The `display: flex` property makes it a flexbox container, and makes all the direct child elements into flex items. The `flex-direction` makes it a column, row direction is default, and `align-items` nows controls the horizontal alignment (in row direction it controls vertical alignment).

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Some things will change. For instance, the `<hr>` element now collapses, so I give it:

```
hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  /* FLEXBOX */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* so you can see better, remove this */
  border: 1px solid red;

  float: right;
  margin-right:140px;
}
.oneline {
  width: 220px;
  height: 144px;
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="oneline">
    <img src="gold.png" align="left">
    <pre>IV-III 12€
    III-II 12€
    II-I 12€
    I-SERIES 15€
    PLAT SERIES 9€
    PL WIN 5€
    </pre>
  </div>
  <p>2 MORE SAME DIVS</p>
  <hr>
  <p>3 MORE SAME DIVS</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, as thankful as i am, the code didnt help my problem, i guess i should give more code then, i uploaded just the HTML file to google drive, if would have some time, i would be even more thankfull than i am right now. This nis the drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4TVZg9n97HHZUee-SFyi162Ql603Zgq/view?usp=sharing